# Delete or edit question on cartographic 'jokes'?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, answered-questions

As Polygeo has pointed out, and placed on hold, my question on Cartographic jokes [Examples of cartographic 'jokes'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/examples-of-cartographic-jokes) was trying to build a list. I hadn't really appreciated that this didn't fit SE.

I had thought about rephrasing the question, perhaps along the lines of inconsistencies introduced to maps because the comment from Mappagnosis is interesting and something I didn't know. But then I thought that it could just end up being a bit a lame question and not that useful to the site.

Plus it does have an answer already that answers the original question and starts the 'list'.

There are downvotes coming in, which is fair enough, and so I went to delete it but the pop-up recommends against it.

[image]

Any thoughts, is it worth salvaging or shall I just lose it?